# cutting a string from string vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string

`Dim query As New ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from win32_processor")
        For Each cpu As ManagementObject In query.Get()
            txtCpu.Text = (cpu("Name"))`

that gives me the entire processor name: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2640M CPU @ 2.80GHz
and what i need is only the 2.80 
so i used mid to cut the not wanted chars (assuming that everytime i use the code that i mentioned above the return will always end with the processors speed) 
   `Mid(txtCpu.Text, Len(txtCpu.Text) - 6, Len(txtCpu.Text) - 3)`
but the answer is always with the GHz = 2.80GHz

the program will run on different computers with different processors so i need to isolate the speed without the word ghz so i will be able to see if the computer has the right Requirements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `Mid(txtCpu.Text, Len(txtCpu.Text) - 6, 3)` - the last parameter is the length of the string you want, not an absolute position.

You could also get the processor speed directly (in MHz) from `cpu["CurrentClockSpeed"]` or `cpu["MaxClockSpeed"]`

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better way of doing this, but I came up with:

```
Dim proc As String = "Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2640M CPU @ 2.80GHz"
Debug.WriteLine(proc)
Dim index As Int32 = proc.IndexOf("@") 'Find the index of the @ symbol.
Debug.WriteLine(index)
proc = proc.Substring(index + 1).Trim 'Take a substring starting to the right of the @ symbol, then trim it.
Debug.WriteLine(proc)
proc = proc.Substring(0, proc.Length - 3) 'Take a substring that cuts off the GHz
Debug.WriteLine(proc)
```

Which gives me:

```
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2640M CPU @ 2.80GHz
31
2.80GHz
2.80
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim str As String = (Cpu("Name"))
txtCpu.Text = str.Substring(InStrRev(str, "@") + 1, (InStrRev(str, "GHz") - (InStrRev(str, "@") + 1)) - 1)
```

or you can directly obtain the clock speed by the code below:

```
    Dim objectQuery As New ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor")
    Dim searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, objectQuery)
    Dim proc As ManagementObject

    For Each proc In searcher.Get()
        txtCpu.text = proc("MaxClockSpeed") ' or proc("CurrentClockSpeed") . it will give you the frequency in MHz, you can convert it to GHz by dividing it by 1024
```

Comment: you actually don't need the string str, you can directly do it like this, (Cpu("Name)).ToString and so on, I used it to make it look simpler =)

Answer (score 0):

In simple you can use sub string method here :

```
Dim str As String = "Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2640M CPU @ 2.80GHz"
Dim ghz As String = str.Substring(str.IndexOf("@") + 1, 5)
```

here the output will be `2.80`